# node-amqp exchange callback not being invoked

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, node-amqp

I have the following code .  My node version is v0.7.0-pre . When I run the code the screen prints

```
 Setup
 Completed setup
```

It does not print the Exchange Callback  message . When I run the

```
rabbitmqctl --list_exchanges
```

command I see the new exchange getting created but the callback is not getting called .  I looked at the test cases and this does not seem to be a covered case . Let me know if this is a bug and if there is a work around

```
var util= require('util')
var amqp = require('amqp');

function setup() {
  console.log("Setup");
  var exchange = conn.exchange('cf1-demo',
    {'type': 'fanout', durable: false},
    function() {
    console.log("Exchange Callback");
 });
 console.log("Completed setup %s", exchange.name);
}
var conn = amqp.createConnection({host:'localhost',
                                    login:'guest',
                                    password:'guest'},
                             {defaultExchangeName: "cf1-demo"});
conn.on('ready',setup);
```

Comment: I would love to answer this question but unfortunately the code you've given me runs fine on my machine, giving this output:

`Setup
Completed setup cf1-demo
Exchange Callback`

Comment: Your code is okay, as @mattbornski mentioned. It could be some caveats regarding node's version — maybe plugin doesn't support newest unstable version due to api changes or something. It definitely works with node 0.6.8 and amqp 0.1.1.

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 11.04 x86_64 .  When I run a rabbitmqctl report I see rabbitMQ version as 2.7.1 . I changed my node to nodev0.6.8 and I still get the same behavior . I am not sure how to find the version of amqp

Comment: You'll see amqp version in `npm ls` output or module-related `package.json` file. By the way, my RabbitMQ version is 2.7.1. Code was tested in Ubuntu x86_64: both 10.10 and 11.10.

Comment: Thanks my amqp version says 0.0.2 . Let me get the latest version and update the results . I thought I did npm install amqp . Is there a different way to do it ?

Comment: Thanks I was able to upgrade to the latest version on node-amqp and things worked . I had to a git clone install of npm install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a problem with node-amqp being the old version . This seemed to be a problem with npm install as far as I can figure